# Xcode can not create provisioning profile for app clip automatically

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, apple-developer, apple-appclips

I am trying to archive an iOS app with its app clip, but I could not manage to achieve it. We have an enterprise developer account and I use Xcode12.0 beta2 (12A6163b).

The steps I did were as following:

- Created a new iOS project
- Added an app clip target
- Added app groups for both app target and app clip target
- Selected automatically manage signing checkbox for both app target and app clip target

For app clip target, I got following error messages:

- The capability associated with "ON_DEMAND_INSTALL_CAPABLE" could not be determined. Please file a bug report at https://feedbackassistant.apple.com and include the Update Signing report from the Report navigator.
- Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching '[BUNDLE_ID_OF_APP_CLIP]'.

Here is screenshot of app target capabilities section:
[image: App target capabilities section]

Here is screenshot of app clip target capabilities section when I selected Xcode managed signing:
[image: app clip target capabilities section auto sign]

---

After I got those error messages, I tried to do this with manual signing. In developer.apple.com I registered a new app-id for app clip target. While creating it, I could not find "On demand install capable" capability and enabled these capabilities.

- App Groups (With enabled app group selected)
- Associated Domains
- Game Center
- In-App Purchase

Here is screenshot of app clip target capabilities section when I manually handled signing:
[image: app clip target capabilities section manual sign]

---

Comment: i dont think you can upload these to store yet, they havne't been released yet

Comment: I have the same issue, can you fix it ?

Comment: @signal check my answer bellow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/app_clips/distributing_your_app_clip),

> Enterprise distribution isn’t available to App Clips.

So you can't use your Enterprise account, even though you were able to create an AppId.

Answer (score 0):

Some steps to try:

1. make sure you are using the latest version of Xcode (12b6 as of this writing)
2. make sure your developer account does NOT have any identifiers for the app clip.
3. remove the app clip completely from your targets and re-add it.
4. turn Automatic Signing on and choose your team. Xcode will automatically make the identifiers you need for the app clip and add them to your dev account.

Comment: I'm using Version 12.2 (12B45b), so yours is 12.0 ?

Comment: I'm running the latest build of xcode (same as you)...is it still not working?

Comment: try going into developer connection and removing the app from there, then turning "automatically manage" off and back on, then selecting your team...and make sure your developer account is active (obv)

Comment: Is it ok to remove the app if the app is already published?

Comment: Is the app published to the app store already?

Comment: Yes, before app clip feature, there’s already a version without app clip published

Comment: Yes , there’s versions without Widget extension on App Store already

Answer (score -1):

Make sure create clip bundle id `xxx.clip` in apple developer website.

If there's one created by Xcode, just delete it and create manually on website.

Then create clip profiles with the `xxx.clip` bundle id.

After that you should work.